# Does electrolyzed reduced water (ERW) extend the lifespan of animals (compared to regular water)?

Tags: medical-science, biology, water, life-expectancy

Among the research interests of Dr. Pablo Campra (of recent graphite-in-Covid-vaccines claim) [is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pZUbpmwXIE) something called electrolyzed reduced water (ERW). One of the (Asian) groups studying this presents is [as](https://bmcproc.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1753-6561-5-S8-P69)

> Electrolyzed reduced water (ERW) is a functional drinking water containing a lot of molecular hydrogen and a small amount of platinum nanoparticles (Pt NPs, Table ​Table1).1). ERW is known to scavenge ROS and protect DNA from oxidative damage [1]. **We previously showed that ERW was capable of extending lifespan of Caenorhabditis elegans by scavenging ROS** [2]. Molecular hydrogen could scavenge ROS and protected brain from oxidative stress.

I looked at their "[2]" self-cited [study](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20944427/) and it does have rather bold findings that ERW extended the lifespan of the worms by 11%-41%.

> worms cultured in ERW-Water medium exhibited a significantly extended lifespan (from 11% to 41%) compared with worms cultured in ultrapure water-Water medium.

Basically, has this kind of research on ERW benn reproduced by other groups? Does ERW extend the lifespan of animals (worms or anything else) when substituted for regular water, which appears to be the main claim there, if I'm not too confused by the unusual/technical terminology in the latter paper ("water-Water" etc.), terminology which however appears omitted in more general presentations...

Comment: I'd question whether any such thing as ERW even exists (outside the world of pseudoscientific buzzword bullshit) before asking whether it has useful properties. Can they demonstrate reproducible properties using credible measurements?

Comment: Does the nematode mentioned even *have* a brain to protect from oxidative stress? And [Frontiers in Microbiology](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmicb.2017.00485/full) writes: "The nematode *Caenorhabditis elegans* is used as a central model system across biological disciplines. Surprisingly, almost all research with this worm is performed in the absence of its native microbiome, possibly affecting generality of the obtained results."

Comment: Hmm, „molecular Hydrogen“ is, well, hydrogen in its usual form. But I doubt that it will still be molecular when dissolved in water. According to Wikipedia, the effect of platinum nanoparticles in biological systems is quite unknown while nanoparticles made from other metals are known to *cause* ROS… I’d rather support @matt_black that ERW isn’t even a thing.